# Programmatically Reloading a C# Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, msbuild

Is it possible to programmatically reload a C# project? In one of my previous [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510295/auto-include-files-in-a-c-project) I needed to add all the CS files in a specific folder, now while this works I find that I have to reload the project every time to so that it can register the new files were added.

So now I need a way to automatically reload after the project had been generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume, for the first time when you output all the DAL files, you are also creating a file with extension .csproj listing in it, all the files you just added in the folder.

***If my assumption above is right*:**
When you want to add more files, you can programatically edit the same .csproj file from your c# code. Then, Visual studio will force the project reload saying it has changed outside the environment.

***If my assumption above is wrong:***
You can create the .csproj file, It should be easy and straight forward.

I am not sure If I got your question right.

Comment: Your assumptions are incorrect as all i am generating is C# code not entire projects. But your approach at solving the problem is unique , i will give it a try and see if it works.